# How to compare socket.id to String?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

In a Node.js I am trying to compare socket.id to a list of id's. At one point the socket id and the id of x element in the list are the same (to the eye) but they're not the same according to the compiler. How do I fix this?

```
        clientsList.forEach(element => {
            console.log('socket id is: ', socket.id.toString())
            console.log('element id is', element.id)
            if (element.id.toString() == socket.id.toString()) {
                index = element.index
            }
        })
        console.log("index: ", index)
```

console output:
socket id is:  lIvSvLg2N3YpQjblAAAD
element id is lIvSvLg2N3YpQjblAAAD
index:  undefined

Comment: Where is `index` defined (by `var`, `const` or `let`)? Also, you don't need to `.toString()` if you're going to compare with `==` since this equality comparison performs a type coercion, while `===` does not.

Comment: try to use the strict comparison(===)

Comment: What is `element.index` ?

Comment: Element.index was a wrong way (of course) of trying to find the index in the array. clientsList.indexOf(element) did work.